# Specific routing in node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a web app to perform CRUD operations on an **array** inside a collection. The collection model is like so:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var website = require('./website');

var plm = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  isPremium: Boolean,
  websites: [],
});

accountSchema.plugin(plm);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);
```

This is my index.ejs file.

```
<% include ./../partials/header.ejs %>
  <h1>
    <%= title %>
  </h1>

  <% if((user.isPremium==true && websites.length<5)||(user.isPremium==false && websites.length<3)) { %>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/websites/add">Add new website</a>
    <% } %>
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr>
          <th>Url</th>
          <% if (user) { %>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <% } %>
        </tr>
        <% for(let i=0; i<websites.length; i++){ let website = websites[i] %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= website %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="/websites/<%= i %>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
              <a href="/websites/delete/<%= i %>" class="btn btn-danger confirmation">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <% } %>
      </table>
      <% include ./../partials/footer.ejs %>
```

What I want to do is: When you click on edit, it takes you to a different *edit* view. I want the *website* shown in index to be in the input field. The edit view looks like this.

```
<% include ../partials/header.ejs %>

<main class="container">

  <h1>Game Details</h1>

  <form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Url: *</label>
      <input name="title" id="title" required value="<%= websiteUrl %>"/>
    </div>
    <%= user %>
    <button class="btn btn-success col-sm-offset-2">Save</button>
  </form>

</main>

<% include ../partials/footer.ejs %>
```

My current routing looks like this.

```
// GET: /websites/:_id - show edit form
router.get('/index', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
  var user = req.user;
  var website = user.website;
  if (
    (user.isPremium == true && websites.length < 5) ||
    (user.isPremium == false && websites.length < 3)
  ) {
    res.render('websites/edit', {
      title: 'Edit websites',
      user: req.user,
      website: website,
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

The problem is when I click the *edit* button it throws an error. `Cannot GET /websites/2`. The 2 changes depending on which I click.

What am I doing wrong?

Again: What I want to do is: When you click on edit, it takes you to a different *edit* view. I want the *website* shown in index to be in the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a different route handler in your Express app for `/websites/edit/:id`.  It appears you're trying to do it inside your `/index` route handler right now.

I've provided some very basic code that shows how you could provide a link to the edit page, allowing you to pass the array index of the website to the editing template.

**However**, the array index is probably not be the best thing to pass, as it may not be easily mapped to a particular website.  Likely you have a database ID that you could include in the `index` view and pass instead.  That's a design choice on your part.  It's not hard to modify the `websites` param that gets passed into the `index` template to be an array of objects instead, for example including the website name *and* a unique ID.  You can ditch the index entirely.

### app.js

```
...
var websites = require('./routes/websites');
...
app.use('/websites', websites);
```

### views/index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <table>
    <% for(let i=0; i<websites.length; i++){ let website = websites[i] %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= website %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/websites/edit/<%= i %>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
        <a href="/websites/delete/<%= i %>" class="btn btn-danger confirmation">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

### routes/websites.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* POST edit page. */
router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('editWebsite', { title: 'THIS IS THE EDITOR' , websiteId: req.params.id});
});

module.exports = router;
```

### views/editWebsite.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %> for editing website <%= websiteId %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <p>Do your editing here.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will `id` work? It's not the objectId. It's an array index

Comment: Also changing the a tag to form doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have only changed the `/index` to `/websites/edit/:id` as you suggested.

Comment: @alex3wielki I've revised my answer to provide example code of how you might do this, and to stick with your table structure and anchor links.  Please have a look.

Comment: Yup that helps. Thanks!